Can I disable the scrollbars in CSS?
I have a Modal dialog that you can see at this link:
https://codepen.io/rgraph/full/KKOyYYK (now updated with the resulting code!)


bar = new RGraph.Bar({
  id: 'cvs',
  data: [8, 4, 6, 5, 3, 4, 5],
  options: {}
}).draw();

bar.canvas.onclick = function(e) {
  ModalDialog.show('string:<div style="text-align: center"><h1>This is a dialog!</h1><br /><button style="font-size: 20pt" onclick="ModalDialog.close()">OK</button></div>');
};
<script src="https://www.rgraph.net/libraries/RGraph.common.core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.rgraph.net/libraries/RGraph.modaldialog.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.rgraph.net/libraries/RGraph.bar.js"></script>

<canvas id="cvs" width="700" height="300"></canvas>

<p>
  tf ty fty fty f ty fty tf ty fty fty f ty fty tf ty fty fty f ty fty tf ty fty fty f ty fty tf ty fty fty f ty fty tf ty fty fty f ty fty tf ty fty fty f ty fty tf ty fty fty f ty fty tf ty fty fty f ty fty ... Add more text to force a ... scrollbar to
  appear
</p>



Now, when you click the chart and show the dialog the page is still scrollable (depending on your screen/browser size).
Previously, I have had a DIV that covers the scrollbars by using an iframe to show a page and then the page that contains the iframe tag shows the dialog - which then covers the iframe and it's scrollbars.
But is there a way to disable scrolling with a single (or a few) CSS properties without this iframe method?

in css: html, body {margin: 0; height: 100%; overflow: hidden}

RESULT: OK, I've updated the codepen example (link above) with some updated code. I ended up going with setting the overflow for the document to hidden and adding some padding-right to prevent the layout shifting (because of the now hidden scrollbar). The exact amount of right-padding to use is calculated from this: var scrollbarWidth = window.innerWidth - document.documentElement.clientWidth;

You could use the following JS when your modal shows:
 const body=document.body.style.overflow="hidden"

then you can reset the behavior to default "scroll" when closing the modal.

While @Sabshanes answer does indeed disable scrolling, it also comes with some problems. Namely, it causes a "bump" effect due to the scrollbar being removed and it might also cause the page to disregard the current scrolling position and scroll to the top.
There are solutions that also work with the overflow attribute, but are a little more advanced than just setting it to hidden. For example you could do something like this: (source)

Define JS function

// define function
function disableBodyScroll(disable = true) {
  if (!window.tempScrollTop) {
    window.tempScrollTop = window.pageYOffset;
  }
  if (disable) {
    document.body.classList.add('disable-scroll');
    document.body.style.top = `-${window.tempScrollTop}px`;
  } else {
    document.body.classList.remove('disable-scroll');
    document.body.style.top = `0px`;
    window.scrollTo({top: window.tempScrollTop});
    window.tempScrollTop = 0;
  }
}


Define CSS class

.disable-scroll {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}


Disable and enable when opening/closing modal

bar.canvas.onclick = function (e)
{
    disableBodyScroll();
    ModalDialog.show(`string:
    <div style="text-align: center">
        <h1>This is a dialog!</h1><br />
        <button style="font-size: 20pt" 
              onclick="disableBodyScroll(false);ModalDialog.close();">OK</button>
    </div>`);
};


A far simpler solution is to work with the window.onscroll event. Simply define two functions disableScrolling() and enableScrolling() like so: (source)
function disableScrolling(){
    var x=window.scrollX;
    var y=window.scrollY;
    window.onscroll=function(){window.scrollTo(x, y);};
}

function enableScrolling(){
    window.onscroll=null;
}

Then use these function in the onclick handler of the canvas:
bar.canvas.onclick = function (e)
{
    disableScrolling();
    ModalDialog.show(`string:
    <div style="text-align: center">
        <h1>This is a dialog!</h1><br />
        <button style="font-size: 20pt" 
          onclick="enableScrolling();ModalDialog.close();">OK</button>
    </div>`);
};


Using the right methods, in the end it comes down to preference. There are many more ways to disable scrolling and you can check a lot of them out here in the answers of this question where I also took these answers from.

This code solves the issue by making the <canvas> responsive, which removes the horizontal scroll. The canvas element adjusts to the available screen width, thanks to setting the width: 100% and limiting the max-width to a specific value (700px in this example). This ensures that the canvas scales according to the screen size without overflowing horizontally.
A vertical scroll may still appear if the content within the <body> exceeds the viewport height (vh), but it will only activate when there’s enough content to go beyond the visible area. The paragraph (<p>) here contains placeholder text, simulating this situation.
Here’s a breakdown of the CSS for the responsive canvas:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://www.rgraph.net/libraries/RGraph.common.core.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.rgraph.net/libraries/RGraph.modaldialog.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.rgraph.net/libraries/RGraph.bar.js"></script>
    <style>
        /* Making the canvas responsive */
        #cvs {
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 700px;
            height: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <canvas id="cvs" width="700" height="300"></canvas>

    <p>
      tf ty fty fty f ty fty
      tf ty fty fty f ty fty
      tf ty fty fty f ty fty
      tf ty fty fty f ty fty
      tf ty fty fty f ty fty
      tf ty fty fty f ty fty
      tf ty fty fty f ty fty
      tf ty fty fty f ty fty
      tf ty fty fty f ty fty
      ... Add more text to force a
      ... scrollbar to appear 
    </p>

    <script>
        // Function to draw the responsive chart
        function drawResponsiveChart() {
            // Sets canvas dimensions based on available width
            const canvas = document.getElementById('cvs');
            const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // Clears the canvas

            // Defines the chart with data and options
            var bar = new RGraph.Bar({
                id: 'cvs',
                data: [8, 4, 6, 5, 3, 4, 5],
                options: {
                    hmargin: 5,
                    shadow: true,
                    colors: ['#5371FF'],
                    labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
                }
            }).draw();

            // Sets the click action for the chart
            bar.canvas.onclick = function(e) {
                ModalDialog.show('string:<div style="text-align: center"><h1>This is a dialog!</h1><br /><button style="font-size: 20pt" onclick="ModalDialog.close()">OK</button></div>');
            };
        }

        // Event to redraw the chart when resizing the window
        window.addEventListener('resize', drawResponsiveChart);

        // Draws the chart for the first time
        drawResponsiveChart();
    </script>

</body>
</html>

